# How to allow only one window in GUI in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, window, nswindowcontroller

I connected a `Menu-Object` with a `Window Controller`. For calling the `Window Controller`, I've added a shortcut. But on pressing the shortcut multiple times, multiple windows are opened. How to call a function, which counts the number of windows, and if it's `0`, it'll open the `Window Controller`, on pressing the shortcut?

I'm using Swift as Programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static variable that is incremented on successful initialization of your view and the decrements on the deinit of the view. You can then check the value in a guard statement before initialization or set the menu availability based on that variable.

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {
  static var count = 0

  override func windowDidLoad() {
    WindowController.count += 1
  }

  deinit {
    WindowController.count -= 1
  }
}

func createWindow() {
  guard WindowController.count = 0 else { return }
  // Create window here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't follow you ... Where to add the variable and how to check them?

Comment: A simpler way to do it is to add the static variable to the WindowController and then in the function that the menu calls to load the menu you can check to see if the variable is 0. In the subclass you can increment the static variable in WindowDidLoad and decrement in Deinit or WindowWillClose.

Comment: Could create an example code? I'm new with Swift, so some terms are confusing me. So ... Where should I create the variable? And then, after creating I have to connect the `Menu-Object` with the `viewDidLoad()`-Function and there I have to check, if the var is 0? Or what are meaning? In conclusion an example could would really help me :)

Comment: I added a code sample in my answer. The WindowController is the window you want to have only one of and the function createWindow() is what your menu item will call.

Comment: I can't connect the `Menu-Object` with the function?

Comment: Well if your using storyboards you use the first responder chain. Havent done it any other way personally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113229/discussion-between-hellotoyou-and-stephen-kac).